MAP, LAMBDA, QUERY Functions Combination to Get the Sum of a Column in Google Sheets
Goal: To calculate the sum of all row entries with the same customer name and invoice number.
Desired Functions: MAP(), LAMBDA(), QUERY()
Issue: The combination of the functions above work when the QUERY() data range is on another worksheet, but does not work when the Query data range is on the same worksheet as the MAP() arrays.
=MAP(B6:B,C6:C,LAMBDA(B,C,IF(OR(B="",C=""),"",QUERY(B6:H,"SELECT SUM(H) WHERE B = '"&B&"' AND C = '"&C&"' GROUP BY B LABEL SUM(H)''",0))))
B: Customer Names
C: Invoice Numbers
H: Payment Amount
L: Where the formula is placed
Each customer can make multiple payments for the same invoice number until they complete the total bill. I can use the SUMIFS() function for this, but I would have to drag the formula all the way down and will not work if new rows are added. Thus, I wanted to use the MAP(), LAMBDA() and QUERY() combination to calculate the sum of all payments made by the customer for a specific invoice number. This is like SUMIFS()  plus ARRAYFORMULA(), the only problem is SUMIFS()  does not work with ARRAYFORMULA()
I kept on staring at my formula, and I don't really see the reason why I'm getting the #N/A error

SUMIFS() will also work with MAP(). Can you please post few sample data and share a sample file?

Your formula seems fine. If invoice numbers are number values then remove single quote from query criteria. Try =MAP(B6:B,C6:C,LAMBDA(B,C,IF(OR(B="",C=""),"",QUERY(B6:H,"SELECT SUM(H) WHERE B = '"&B&"' AND C = "&C&" GROUP BY B LABEL SUM(H)''",0)))).

Based on the sample data in @Alma_Matters' post, an alternative using QUERY only;
=QUERY(B2:H, "Select B, C, Sum(H) Where B Is Not Null Group By B, C Label Sum(H) ''")

.


Thanks! I will try this.

Alternative solution using filter:
Based on my understanding of your provided data, you want to calculate the sum of all row entries with the same customer name and invoice number.
Try this workaround: Instead of using MAP, I used the JOIN and BYROW function to create unique values to work with. Instead of QUERY, I used FILTER.
Formula:
=LET(nv,BYROW(B2:C, LAMBDA(r, join("|",r))), amount, H2:H, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(BYROW(UNIQUE(nv), LAMBDA(filt,HSTACK(SPLIT(filt,"|"),SUM(FILTER(amount, nv = filt))))),ROWS(UNIQUE(nv))-1,3))

Sample Output:

Reference/s:
Filter
BYROW

Thanks! I will try this.
